# Nodejs SSL-certificate verification

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate

I am trying to implement a payment system and I was given a sample code for ssl certificate verification which was written on PHP. The code is as follows:

```
echo "<strong>1. Verify Certifcate</strong><blockquote>";
#Get DigestValue
echo "<strong>DigestValue:</strong><br>",$sigDigest=$xmlDoc- 
>documentElement->getElementsByTagName("DigestValue")->item(0)->nodeValue," 
<br>";
$signedInfo=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("SignedInfo")->item(0)->C14N(true, 
true);

#Get SignatureValue
$signature = base64_decode($xmlDoc->documentElement- 
>getElementsByTagName("SignatureValue")->item(0)->nodeValue);

#Check Certificate
$ok = openssl_verify($signedInfo, $signature, $pubKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
echo "<p><strong>Status:</strong> ", $ok == 1 ? "Valid" : "Invalid", " 
Cetificate.</p></blockquote><hr>";
```

The problem I'm facing is that I am trying to do the same thing on Node.js but when I try to verify it, it's returning false every time. I'm aware that there's a similar question asked here, I tried his solution but that hasn't been working as well.

Basically, I'm trying to do the same thing as this line is doing.

```
$ok = openssl_verify($signedInfo, $signature, $pubKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
```

Here is the code. Verification method is in the checkSignature function.

```
exports.verifyTest = function (req, res) {

  var keyPath = 'certs/result.xml';
  var xml = fs.readFileSync(keyPath);

  var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
  parseString(xml,
    {trim : true },
    function (err, result) {

    if(result.Message && result.Message.OrderStatus == 'APPROVED') {
        var orderId  = result.Message.OrderID,
        signature = result['Message']['Signature'][0]['SignatureValue'],
        signedInfo = result['Message']['Signature'][0]['SignedInfo'][0] 
        ['Reference'][0]['DigestValue'];

        var valid = checkSignature(signedInfo+"", signature+"");
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Гүйлгээ амжилттай " + valid
        });

    } else {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Unsuccessful"
        });
    }

  });

};


function checkSignature(data, sig) {


  var pub = fs.readFileSync('certs/public.cert').toString()
  var verify = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA1');
  verify.update(data);
  var result = verify.verify(pub,sig,'base64');
  return result;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show your code. There's no way we can help you diagnose code we can't see. Sample input data would also be helpful.

Comment: Hey, I just added my code.